# how to match exact subdomain with grep ignoring others

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

how can I match audio.itunes.apple.com and ignore http://streamingaudio.itunes.apple.com in a log file using grep?

Comment: What have you tried this far, and why do you suspect it did not work? Also, a sample of the actual log file would be helpful.

Comment: @ramkorla what sort of content is there prior to `audio.itunes.apple.com`? like space, start or line, etc? that can be used...

Answer (score 2):

Most `grep` implementations support a `-w` option for *word* match:

```
grep -wF audio.itunes.apple.com
```

Or for `grep` implementation (like Solaris') that can't use `-w` in combination with `-F`:

```
grep -w 'audio\.itunes\.apple\.com'
```

Would only find lines that contain `audio.itunes.apple.com` provided it's not preceded nor followed by a *word character* (word characters being alphanumericals or underscore (restricted to the single-bytes ones for versions of GNU `grep` prior to 2.19)).  Some `grep` implementations like on Solaris also restrict the matched string to start (though not necessarily end) with a word character unless that non-word character is at the beginning of the line (though that makes no difference in this case as the first character of the matched portion is always going to be `a`, a word character).

So here it would match on `http://audio.itunes.apple.com` because `/` is a non-word character, but not on `http://streamingaudio.itunes.apple.com` as the `g` that precedes `audio` is a word character.

The POSIX equivalent would be:

```
grep -E '(^[^[:alnum:]_])audio\.itunes\.apple\.com([^[:alnum:]_]|$)'
```

Or with BREs:

```
grep -x '\(.*[^[:alnum:]_]\)\{0,1\}audio\.itunes\.apple\.com\([^[:alnum:]_].*\)\{0,1\}'
```

Some `grep` implementations, including GNU `grep` support a `\<` regexp operator which matches at the transition between a non-word and a word (Solaris `grep`'s `\<` has the same odd extra restriction as for `-w` above). So you can use:

```
grep '\<audio\.itunes\.apple\.com'
```

with those `grep` implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Please use -v, --invert-match

Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)

grep -v http://streamingaudio.itunes.apple.com